# Command to copy 20000 small files in 40 diferent directories

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep

I have here a directory with about 40 small files, and wish to copy them into 4 different directories, distributed by number of files.

Following is an example of what should be done, with 40 files divided in directories of 10 files each. The following criteria of number, or maybe minutes, with each directory having files with same minute in timestamp:

```
schwaiger@ffurtpc:/home/schwaiger/files/$ ll
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  2 schwaiger schwaiger 36864 out 19 12:19 ./
drwxr-xr-x 52 schwaiger schwaiger  4096 out 19 14:05 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32229 out 19 09:18 00001-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32243 out 19 09:18 00002-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32243 out 19 09:18 00002-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32294 out 19 09:18 00004-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32267 out 19 09:18 00005-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32287 out 19 09:18 00006-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32294 out 19 09:18 00007-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32267 out 19 09:18 00008-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32287 out 19 09:18 00009-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32293 out 19 09:18 00010-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32298 out 19 09:17 00011-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32289 out 19 09:17 00012-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32298 out 19 09:17 00013-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32289 out 19 09:17 00014-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32308 out 19 09:17 00015-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32340 out 19 09:17 00016-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32308 out 19 09:17 00017-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32340 out 19 09:17 00018-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32329 out 19 09:17 00019-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32324 out 19 09:17 00020-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32300 out 19 09:20 00021-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32316 out 19 09:20 00022-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32315 out 19 09:20 00023-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32310 out 19 09:20 00024-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32319 out 19 09:20 00025-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32318 out 19 09:20 00026-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32341 out 19 09:20 00027-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32323 out 19 09:20 00028-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32341 out 19 09:20 00029-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32319 out 19 09:20 00030-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32350 out 19 09:22 00031-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32389 out 19 09:22 00032-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32289 out 19 09:22 00033-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32298 out 19 09:22 00034-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32318 out 19 09:22 00035-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32341 out 19 09:22 00036-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32243 out 19 09:22 00037-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32243 out 19 09:22 00038-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32289 out 19 09:22 00039-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32298 out 19 09:22 00040-capture.jpg
```

That should be distributedin directories of 10:

```
    schwaiger@ffurtpc:/home/schwaiger/files/a01$ ll
    total 10
    drwxr-xr-x  2 schwaiger schwaiger 36864 out 19 12:19 ./
    drwxr-xr-x 52 schwaiger schwaiger  4096 out 19 14:05 ../
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32229 out 19 09:18 00001-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32243 out 19 09:18 00002-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32243 out 19 09:18 00002-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32294 out 19 09:18 00004-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32267 out 19 09:18 00005-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32287 out 19 09:18 00006-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32294 out 19 09:18 00007-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32267 out 19 09:18 00008-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32287 out 19 09:18 00009-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32293 out 19 09:18 00010-capture.jpg

    schwaiger@ffurtpc:/home/schwaiger/files/a02$ ll
    total 10
    drwxr-xr-x  2 schwaiger schwaiger 36864 out 19 12:19 ./
    drwxr-xr-x 52 schwaiger schwaiger  4096 out 19 14:05 ../
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32298 out 19 09:17 00011-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32289 out 19 09:17 00012-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32298 out 19 09:17 00013-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32289 out 19 09:17 00014-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32308 out 19 09:17 00015-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32340 out 19 09:17 00016-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32308 out 19 09:17 00017-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32340 out 19 09:17 00018-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32329 out 19 09:17 00019-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32324 out 19 09:17 00020-capture.jpg

    schwaiger@ffurtpc:/home/schwaiger/files/a03$ ll
    total 10
    drwxr-xr-x  2 schwaiger schwaiger 36864 out 19 12:19 ./
    drwxr-xr-x 52 schwaiger schwaiger  4096 out 19 14:05 ../
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32300 out 19 09:20 00021-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32316 out 19 09:20 00022-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32315 out 19 09:20 00023-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32310 out 19 09:20 00024-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32319 out 19 09:20 00025-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32318 out 19 09:20 00026-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32341 out 19 09:20 00027-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32323 out 19 09:20 00028-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32341 out 19 09:20 00029-capture.jpg
    -rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32319 out 19 09:20 00030-capture.jpg

schwaiger@ffurtpc:/home/schwaiger/files/a04$ ll
total 10
drwxr-xr-x  2 schwaiger schwaiger 36864 out 19 12:19 ./
drwxr-xr-x 52 schwaiger schwaiger  4096 out 19 14:05 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32350 out 19 09:22 00031-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32389 out 19 09:22 00032-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32289 out 19 09:22 00033-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32298 out 19 09:22 00034-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32318 out 19 09:22 00035-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32341 out 19 09:22 00036-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32243 out 19 09:22 00037-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32243 out 19 09:22 00038-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32289 out 19 09:22 00039-capture.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 schwaiger schwaiger 32298 out 19 09:22 00040-capture.jpg
```

How could that be done, preferably with `awk`, `sed`, `egrep` or even `bash`?

Comment: What determines which of the 30 or 40 directories they end up into?

Comment: As a a reminder, this site isn't for doing your "homework": please, provide the code/commands you already tested, the result you got and the errors you met. Then we can help.

Comment: so 40*10 is significantly less than 20000.  What should be done with all remaining 19600 files?

Comment: Can you guarantee that there are exactly 40 different minute timestamps, not more or less?

Comment: What determines which of the 30 or 40 directories they end up in?

Comment: Maybe one of the people who upvoted the question can explain it?

Comment: @Ferrari21 are you actually meaning that the total number of files should be divided by 40, that the `result` (quotient) is the number of files that should end up into each one of 40 directories, and that the first directory will get the first `result` files, ordered by timestamp, and so on?

Comment: Thats just estimating. As in this example was distributed 40 files in 4 directories of 10 files, 20000 files would be distributed in directories of 500 files.

Comment: According to my understanding, main objective is to copy that list of files in directories containing given number of files each. Already started to work in it here.

Answer (score 2):

Even if i don't like this kind of question where it's obvious that you just didn't searched a bit before asking, here is a beginning of solution:

```bsh
for file in * ; do 
   dstdir=$(stat -c %X "${file}")
   if [ ! -d "${dstdir}" ]; then
       mkdir "${dstdir}"
   fi
   mv "${file}" "${dstdir}"
done
```

**EDITED SINCE OP TOTALLY CHANGED ORIGINAL QUESTION**

```
i=0
dstdir=0
for file in *; do
  if [[ "$((i++))" -gt 10 ]] ; then
    dstdir=$((dstdir + 1))
  fi  
  if [ ! -d "${dstdir}" ] ; then
     mkdir ${dstdir}
  fi
  mv $file ${dstdir}/
done
```

Basic algorithm. 
Adjust `i` test for your needs. 
Remind that `$(( ))` is to do arithmetic in bash (not sure it's sh compatible)

Comment: Wouldn't this create a new directory for each unique timestamp and not specifically 40 directories?

Comment: That created 7000 directories from 90000 files, too much. There should be another way.

Comment: @Ferrari21: You still haven't explained how the files should be distributed.  You have said conflicting and incomplete things.

Comment: This assumes a Linux `stat`, if I'm not mistaken.  The user has not said what Unix they are using.

Comment: @Jesse_b Just removed timestamp thing, it would be done only by nominal number of files in directory, as of: directories of 10 files.

Comment: @Ferrari21: you just asked a poor question with only one real criteria for classifcation: the timestamp. I stricly answered it: order it by timestamp... then you changed question. Next time, think a bit more about your need so that you can explain it clearly...